# Can't overwrite with a zero value in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I've added a bunch of values to the stack. Now, I want to go back and replace every other word on the stack with a zero. Here's my code:

```
TwosLoop:
bgt $t0, $a0, EndTwosLoop
    addi $t0, $t0, 2
    sw $0, 8($sp)
    j TwosLoop
EndTwosLoop:
```

For some reason, it doesn't replace that location on the stack with a zero...

Comment: I'm not well versed in MIPS assembly, but it looks like you're storing zero to the same location each time through the loop: `sw $0, 8($sp)` - `$sp` is never modified (unless `$t0` is an alias for it).

Comment: You always write to the same location.

Comment: It sure looks that way! Let's see if I'm just an idiot.... Checking code...

Comment: Yep, that was the problem!